# jquery .load working but unreadable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know why I can use `.load` to load a very specific bit of information to a page but then when I try to read back the loaded information I am just returned `null`

this is the jquery I am using to load this bit of information

```
$(function(){
    $('#code').load('stuff.html #specificstuff');
});
```

And this is the code I am using to repeat what is in `#code`

```
var content = document.getElementById('#code');
document.write(content);
```

But when this is run, I am just getting back `null`

Comment: Is the page you're attempting to load on a different domain?

Comment: @MarioJVargas nope same domain, and the .load function does work but just wont be read back

Comment: What type of element is `#code`? And does the stuff.html page contain an element with ID `specificstuff`?

Comment: Why are you using `document.write`?

Comment: @MarioJVargas it is a paragraph and yes it does, that is a span

Comment: And document.write(arg) needs a String as argument, not a Dom object. It will stringify it as something similar to `[object HTMLDivElement]`. 
Try using `content.innerHTML` (although you loose the wrapping div)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('#code');
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('code');
```

That being said... I have no clue why you are using `document.write` in the first place.

And you need to wait for the load to finish, so it would make more sense to do:

```
$('#code').load('stuff.html #specificstuff', function(){
    var content = document.getElementById('code').html();
    document.write(content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.load()` is asyncronous, so your code:

```
var content = document.getElementById('#code');
document.write(content);
```

gets executed *before* the actual content is loaded.

Put it in a callback function like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#code').load('stuff.html #specificstuff', function(){
        var content = document.getElementById('code');
        document.write(content);
    });
});
```

so it gets executed *after* the content has done loading.

That said, `document.write(content);` in this case is useless, as `$('#code').load()` replaces the content of the element with `id="code"` with the content of the element `#specificstuff` of the file `stuff.html`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have used exactly what you said but found I am getting simply [object HTMLSpanElement]

Comment: @user3743076 that's because `document.getElementById('code')` returns the DOM node. Probably `document.write(content.innerHTML) is what you want.